# Print location of repeating columns on RDLC report

Tags: rdlc, dynamics-business-central

I am working on a document RDLC report in Visual Studio with the RDLC designer and have a column group to the right of the rest of the layout containing a matrix that gets populated with images.

[RDLC layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulzDO.png)

This prints the matrix on the second page and I want them to print on the first page of the document.

[Printed version of report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d0rf.png)

I tried adding the table into the row group in-line with the rest of the report but the page would then break after each value (image) that was returned. Is there a way to make that all the values of the column group would print on the bottom of the first page only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with RDLC layouts is not easy and often almost impossible without knowing the structure of the dataset.

One suggestion based on your provided information would be to do the following:

1. Add a `Rectangle` to the `TablixCell` which the green arrow points to.
2. Move the `Tablix` with the images into the added `Rectangle`

The end result should be that the `Rectangle` becomes the parent of the `Tablix` with the images.

Also note that the report engine will create new pages if your content width exceeds the defined paper size excl. margins.